# "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" with Nuxt3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt3

I'm currently using Nuxt 3 version 3.6.5 and TypeScript version 5.1.6. Here's my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.12.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.13.0",
    "consola": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.28",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nuxt-swiper": "^1.1.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.33",
    "swiper": "^9.4.0",
    "vee-validate": "^4.8.4",
    "vue-draggable": "^2.0.6",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image-edge": "1.0.0-28001428.0aa03b6",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "6.6.5",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.7",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "@vee-validate/zod": "^4.8.4",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
    "nuxt-icon": "^0.3.3",
    "nuxt-lodash": "^2.4.1",
    "nuxt-security": "^0.12.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.6",
    "prisma": "^4.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
```

Whenever I use useFetch(), I always encounter an editor error stating:

"Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."

```
const { data, error } = await useFetch<Styles>('/api/portfolio_style', {
    method: 'get',
  });
```

However, I've already provided generic types. How can I resolve this issue? (I'm wondering if it might be related to some packages or VScode extensions?)

By the way, running npm run dev and executing the program has no issues at all. The problem only persists within the editor, with this error continuously appearing.

I had tried rolling back the TypeScript version, but it didn't help much. Maybe it could be an issue related to TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)?

Comment: By the way, I've noticed something. It seems that only the first API within the <script> section of each file (from top to bottom) is triggering this editor error.

Comment: Consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [The type is too complex for TypeScript to compute](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30188#issuecomment-478938437).  You can ignore it, or work out a way to "compute the types that cause problems step by step" as described in the linked github comment (which I would not know how to help with)